# Websphere MQ :: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect error

Tags: ibm-mq

We have a Java application to read and write messages to Queue

when we run the get or  put operation to read MQ messages or write to MQ multiple times continuously,  at some point get or put operation will fail with the below error

```
The test connection for ibm_mq_appauth failed. [SDK_APP_COM_20000] error [error [MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2009 MQJE016: MQ queue manager closed channel immediately during connect Closure reason = 2009]]
```

one of the reasons can be the connection channel status exceeds 100

[image: Connection Count on queue manager]

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=function-server-connection-channel-limits

once the connection count decreases the get or put operation works fine

How can we increase the connection count? what is the solution available to resolve this issue?

now the only workaround that we are following is, to wait till the connection count decreases or restart Queue Manager (with this we lose the data)

Answer (score 0):

The connection count itself is not the issue - there is no maximum on the total number of connections made into the queue manager. There are however, maximums on channels, and also on the SVRCONN channel definition. If you have seen a pattern where the problem occurs when the connection count is higher, then it is possible that you are hitting a maximum defined for the channels. You should check the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG for confirmation that this is what you are hitting. It will be clear when you look in the error log.

To fix it, it will depend on exactly what maximum you are hitting, as there are a few.

The first is the `MaxChannels` setting in `qm.ini`. You can increase this by adding the following lines to your queue manager's `qm.ini` file and then restarting the queue manager. The default value if not set to something explicitly is 100, so it is possible to hit this.

```
Channels:
   MaxChannels=200
```

I suspect that will be your issue, but just in case it is not, it is also worth checking the values of the `MAXINST` and `MAXINSTC` attributes on the SVRCONN channel that you are using and if these have been set to low values, to increase those. They both default to 999999999 so it is less likely that you would hit these without knowing about them.

**Reference Material for further reading**

- [Channels stanza of the qm.ini file](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=qmini-channels-stanza-file)
- [DEFINE CHANNEL - Server-Connection](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=channel-server-connection)
- [MaxChannels vs DIS QMSTATUS CONNS](https://mqgem.wordpress.com/2016/06/23/maxchannels-vs-dis-qmstatus-conns/)

Answer (score 0):

Follow Morag's advice on increasing the number of connections per channel.

> when we run the get or put operation to read MQ messages or write to
> MQ multiple times continuously, at some point get or put operation
> will fail with the below error

Interesting comment. My first thought is that you have some poor coding in your application.

(1) Is your application connecting and staying connected while it performs gets and puts throughout the day or days?

(2) Or is your application connecting, doing some gets and puts but then returning, or the thread ends but never disconnects from the queue manager?

Because it sounds like your application is doing #2. This would explain why your channel connection count keeps rising. It is bad coding practise to not disconnect from the queue manager when the application is done whatever it was doing. The MQ client library will ***NOT*** automatically perform the disconnection for your application.

Bottomline is that even if you increase the channel max connection limit from 100 to 300, your poorly coded application will eventually use all 300 connections and then have the same problem.  Therefore, you need to fix the code and ensure it disconnects from the queue manager when done.